# 'this' in a function VS 'this' in a method

Tags: javascript, this

From Javascript-Garden:

```
Foo.method = function() {
  function test() {
    //this is set to the global object
  }
test();
}
```

In order to gain access to Foo from within test, it is necessary to create a local variable inside of method that refers to Foo:

```
Foo.method = function() {
  var that = this;
  function test(){
    //Use that instead of this here
  }
test();
}
```

Could anyone explain this? As far as I understood, `this` refers to the global object if it's called in the global scope. But here it's called inside of a function, which is inside a method (first example). Why exactly does it refer to the global object, while the second example doesn't?

Comment: `this` *always* refers to the global object when a function is called normally (`func()`) (unless `this` was explicitly bound before). Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Regarding *"[...] while the second example doesn't?"*: It does (inside `test` of course)! Where the function is defined or called does not matter. Only *how* it is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I understood, this refers to the global object if it's called in the global scope.

No. `this` will refer to the default object if the function is called without explicit context. The scope is irrelevant. (In strict mode it will refer to `undefined` instead).

> Why exactly does it refer to the global object

<del>We can't tell what it refers to.</del> The value of `this` is determined by how the function is *called*, not how it is defined.

Now you have updated the example, we can see that it is called without context, so `this` (in the inner function) will be the default object, which in a web browser is `window` (it would be `undefined` in strict mode).

> while the second example doesn't?

In the second example, the inner function doesn't use `this` (which will have the same value as the previous example).

The second example uses `that` instead. `that` is defined in the scope of the outer function and is set to whatever the value of `this` is when that function is called.

Assuming that function is called as `Foo.method()` then (outer) `this` (and hence `that`) will be `Foo` because that is the context on which `method` was called.

Comment: `The value of this is determined by how the function is called not how it is defined.` Well put!

Answer (score 3):

`this` in a function isn't set when you define the function. It's only dynamically defined to the receiver of the function call.

If you call `foo.test()`, `this` in `test` will be `foo`.

But if you do

```
var f = foo.test;
f();
```

then `this` in `f` (which is `foo.test`) will be the external object (window if you're executing it at the root level).

It would be the same with

```
foo.test.call(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example uses a closure to place the outer functions variables on the scope chain of the inner function.

```
Foo.method = function() {
  var that = this;
  function test(){
    //This function has access to the outer variables scope chain.
  }
}
```

Comment: "A call to test is actually implicitly preceded by the global object." — That would make it impossible to directly call any function not defined in the global scope. It is just given the context of the default object (unless you are using strict mode).

Comment: @Quentin Your right I thought I was onto something there, guess not.